# PhpStorm multi-docker hostname resolution

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a fully set up docker environment furnished with Xdebug, properly set up with PhpStorm. My environment has multiple containers running for different functions. All appears to work great. CLI/Web interaction both stop at breakpoints as they should, no problems. However ...

I have a code snippet as follows:

```
// test.php
$host = gethostbyname('db'); //'db' is the name of the other docker box, created with docker-compose
echo $host;
```

If I run this through bash in the 'web' docker instance:

```
php test.php
172.21.0.2
```

If I run it through the browser:

```
172.21.0.2
```

If I run it via the PhpStorm run/debug button (Shift+F9):

```
docker://docker_web:latest/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1 /opt/project/test.php
db
```

It doesn't resolve! Why would that be, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please note that PhpStorm does not use a running container, it starts a new one. And when it does it, it doesn't use the existing network. You should use `depends_on` and link services to each other to ensure them starting in the correct order. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-37986

Comment: Ah, I fixed it. While the problem wasn't exactly as you stated, it did put me on the right path. Thanks very much for that! I'll document my solution now.

Comment: hey hey did I understand it correctly that you have multiple containers running with different applications and xdebug works fine accross them? 
As an example Container A talks to Container B and xdebug stops at a breakpoint in container B? 

If so, how is your set up can't seem to get mine working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, my docker environment is built with docker-compose, and all the relevant containers are on the same network, and have a proper depends_on hierarchy.

However. PHPStorm was actually set up to use plain docker, rather than docker-compose. It was connecting fine to the docker daemon, but because the container wasn't being build composer-aware, it wasn't leveraging the network layout that was defined in my docker-compose.yml. Once I told PHPStorm to use docker-compose, it worked fine.

As an aside, I noticed that after I run an in-IDE debug session after already loading my container, and causes the container to exit when the script ends. To get around this, I had to create a mirror debug container for PHPStorm to use on demand. My config is as follows:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web: &web
    build: ./web
    container_name: dev_web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECTS_DIR}/project:/srv/project
      - ./web/logs/httpd:/var/log/httpd
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    networks:
      - backend

  web-debug:
    << : *web
    container_name: dev_web_debug
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    command: php -v

  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: dev_db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

This allows me to be able to do in-IDE spot debuging on the fly without killing my main web container.